# javascript not recognizing php variables

Tags: javascript, php

something.php (that actually functions as a .js file )

```
<?php $var = "test"; ?>
console.log( <?= $var; ?>);
```

Why would this not work?

Comment: How does it not work, what ***do*** you get in the console ?

Comment: You're using [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) that may not be enabled if your php is > v5.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign your PHP string to a JS variable first.

```
<?php $php_var = 'test'; ?>

<script>
// We're assuming that $php_var is a string.
// Behaviour would be different for other variable types.
var js_var = '<?php echo $php_var; ?>';
console.log(js_var);
</script>
```

Or, if for some reason you have to dump it straight into the console,

```
console.log('<?php echo $php_var ?>');
```

Once again, we're assuming here that `$php_var` a string.

Comment: I will now try to make it work with an array, which made me stumble upon this issue.
I really love this community, thank you so much for a) good answers and b) such fast replies.
Thanks !!!!!

Comment: With arrays and objects you'll have to run your PHP variables through `json_encode()` and only then assign the result to JS variables. Single quotes must be removed around the PHP echo statement in this case (as is the case for integers and floats as well).

Answer (score 1):

you have missed double quotes .use this code.it works.

```
<?php $var = "test"; ?>
console.log("<?= $var; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is looking for a variable `test`, not the string `"test"`. There should be an error stating that in the console. Viewing the page source you would see:

```
console.log(test);
```

so add quotes

```
console.log( "<?= $var; ?>" );
```

Just need to make sure that the actual string has `"` encoded.

Comment: Correct. How do I make it work for strings/arrays ?